# Hibernate or 'Do-It-Yourself"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to admit that I didn't have the luck to use JPA, so If my question will sound weird please don't blame me. AFAIK Hibernate seems to be a wide spread implementation of JPA. The question is: Are there any cases where importing Hibernate can be avoided? My boss said that we haven't to "overhead" our project with external things and could implement the necessary features of JPA ourselves. But almost everybody says that reinventing the wheel is just senseless and recommend to use ready implementations of JPA. Now I'm a bit confused and don't know what is the best way to go.

Comment: Either it is your boss deciding, or yourself. If yourself, do not "reinvent the wheel". On the other side: for a startup or demo project: use what you know better.

Comment: I wish someone to write a book 'How to stop worrying and start coding JDBC' )  ORMs like hibernate often becomes very clumsy and eager for resources, remembering some situations it was tens time slower then simple jdbc queries. Moreover is not a big deal to map some data from DB to some entity, especially when using some wrappers like Srping JDBC Template

Comment: "The majority of bosses are not well informed"

Comment: @Neil Stockton In my case my boss is the leading developer of our team.

Comment: @ancalled What about transactions and transaction propagation?  But supporting different databases (i.e having a product for different databases)? It is time-efficient to develop with JPA, and not most performant.

Comment: if he's trying to dissuade you from unnecessarily adding a 3p dependency he/she is probably wiser than most.

Comment: @Andrei I  The term of transaction is came to java from database world I think, so you can use all kind of commit/rollbacks in most of modern databases. Also as support of ANSI SQL syntax, yes, there is a difference f.e. in Mysql's `limit 0, 100` and Oracle's `rownum < 100`, but you also have a lot of db-specific benefits like really complex joining of tables, aggregates, views etc, etc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the scale of your project: the cost of learning hibernate vs the cost of rolling your own persistence mechanism.

Also worth considering other payoffs: will you be likely to use hibernate in the future? Then the time invested will be worthwhile.

On the other hand it is always good to eliminate 3rd party dependencies where possible. If your problem is small, an external library can often provide an unnecessary layer of indirection when trying to diagnose issues.

More on the topic here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you actually do with the database. If you mainly work with highly tabular data and you rely much on bulk queries then JPA will not be that useful and if you have no prior experience it will be hard to use it effectively.

If on the other hand you are manipulation complex object structures that need to be persisted then JPA is very useful.

Note that Hibernate is not the only JPA provider. So maybe your boss would be happier with for instance EclipseLink as this is the reference implentation.